# C# DataTable OrderBy wrong sort

Tags: c#, datatable

I wrote some code and got wrong sort.

Can anyone can explain?

```
          List<double> ii = new List<double>() { 1.2043801874, 1.2077423953, 1.9349906628 ,2.3225299029 ,2.4545523619 ,
                    2.7680609859 , 2.8905747132 ,2.9940913416 , 3.0737675373 ,3.2299437327 , 3.260846366  ,3.3004602464 ,
                    3.4006307085 , 3.513391731  ,3.6214660094 ,4.8013057532 , 5.8670500438 ,6.1397306939 , 7.1040729766 ,
                    8.0858126519 , 1.2356543405 ,1.3799212012 ,1.3976222125 ,1.5461464187 ,1.7162840558 ,1.7511717786 ,
                    10.2544634898, 2.0069778978 ,2.0262575594 ,2.0868135866 ,2.1595079322 ,2.25748278   ,2.4881372712 ,
                    2.9191324991 ,3.0847910479 , 3.1859703596 ,5.39216447   ,5.3949224157 ,9.3404802167 ,};
        DataTable input = new DataTable();
        input.Columns.Add("i");
        foreach(Double i in ii)
        {
            DataRow row = input.NewRow();
            row["i"] = i;
            input.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        DataTable Notsorted = input.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["i"]).CopyToDataTable();
```

the result [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbMxK.png)

Comment: `input.Columns.Add("i");` will add a default string column so you get an alphabetical sort.  You should add a column with a datatype of double

Comment: I see an awful lot of DataTable code on SO.  I haven't used a DataTable in about 10 years.  What is the continuing attraction of DataTables now that we have Generics and LINQ.  They were great in the pre-historic object-only era (before Generics).

Comment: Probably because they still works?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a column you should specify its DataType otherwise it is assumed to be a string and the string "10.2544634898" is alphabetically lower than all strings that begins with "2", "3" etc...

```
input.Columns.Add("i", typeof(double));
```

Now, the sorting on the column will work treating correctly the numbers as numbers.

Comment: can i cast to double without declare on add function?

Comment: No there is no cast from string to double. You could Convert or Parse the string stored in the table to a double. But why? You have a list of doubles then why converting them to strings and then back to doubles?